# 2010 Hyundai Accent brakes squeal/stick when wet

Tags: brakes, hyundai, accent

I've noticed that my 2010 Hyundai Accent has a peculiar issue. If it's raining and I first start driving and apply the brakes, maybe the first two or three times as I'm approaching a stop the brakes will all of a sudden lock up and squeal quite badly. My neighbor has the same car (I'm not sure the year) and he says his does the same thing. Is there anything I can do to fix this issue? I'm not a mechanic, but its annoying enough that I would attempt to fix it myself if its possible. Thank you very much!

Comment: I take it you are past the 60k mile mark?

Comment: yeah. I'm at about 67k.

Comment: Does this vehicle have antilock brakes? Also, was this happening prior to the 60k mark? If it was, you may have recourse through Hyundai, as this could possibly be covered under the 5yr/60k warranty, depending on how froggy your dealership is.

Comment: It does have ABS and yes it happened before the 60k mark. Thanks, I'll definitely check with the dealer.

Comment: Does it do it only on the first stop of the day or after sitting overnight?

Comment: Base model accents don’t have abs. They lock up very easy in rain and cold. I own the same car. Nothing you can do to fix it unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

As it only happens when wet and cold, I suspect that the friction between pad and disc is increased by the rain water enough to cause the grabbing. One thought is that the the water is turned to steam and effectively increases the brake pressures effect on the brakes as the steam is unable to escape from between pad and disc. You should never the less run it past your mechanic to fully check the brakes.